# How to write SQL Insert Query in Yaml file using GitHub Actions?

Tags: sql-server, yaml, azure-sql-database, github-actions

I am trying to insert data into My database tables which resides on Azure SQL Database using git hub action pipelines .connection strings are working fine .Need to Know how we write inset scripts of sql in yaml file. Any Reference links will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you already got the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482589/how-to-write-sql-insert-query-in-yaml-file-using-g.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute any SQL Query through GitHub Actions then you can create a SQL Script file (with your SQL Insert statements) in your repository at root level and refer the SQL file using SQL-file: attribute under azure/sql-action@v1 section of YAML. Once build is run, it will pick up the script file and execute it on the specific azure SQL server. Please refer to the below YAML snippet for your reference.

name: SQL for GitHub Actions

```
on:   push:
     branches: [ master ]   pull_request:
     branches: [ master ]
    
      jobs:    build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v1
     - uses: azure/login@v1
       with:
         creds: ${<!-- -->{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        
     - uses: azure/sql-action@v1
       with:
        server-name: 'servername.database.windows.net'
        connection-string: ${<!-- -->{ secrets.AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING }}
        sql-file: './test_sql_script.sql'
     # Azure logout 
     - name: logout
       run: |
            az logout
```

SQL script file:
[image]

Content:
[image]

When the workflow runs, it executes the SQL script file as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Does this method also work for non azure DBs?